# icomoon - wide fonts rendering incorrectly only on a Chrome browser and on actual android phone

Tags: android, google-chrome, fonts, rendering

I have an issue where icons on an android phone using chrome browsing are not rendering correctly.

This seems to only happen on icons that are wide.

The behavior seems to be pretty inconsistent and will range from:

1. floating off the screen to the top left.
2. completely disappearing and not rendering.
3. partial rendering

Is this a chrome bug?  I've narrowed down the issue to only icons that are wide and it is only happening on the chrome browser on an actual phone. Mobile view on desktop for Chrome displays the icons correctly.  It only happens when I switch to an actual phone.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Chrome bug. There is an easy workaround for it: Put your icon in a canvas that's not too wide.